# sed to exclude directories

Tags: sed

I try to replace many files at once with sed using * as filename. However it tries to process directories too, and gives error and terminates. Is there a simple way to overcome this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly *how* you're using `sed` here but the normal way to process only regular files in UNIX is with the `find` command, something like:

```
find . -type f -exec sed 's/Hello/Goodbye/g' {} ';'
```

The type restricts you to regular files, not directories or FIFOs or any other sort of filesystem magic.

If you run `man find` on your system, you will see a plethora of other options you can use.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to linux/unix shell commands, why is it that when I run this  it spams my screen with the contents of many files but never changes anything?

Comment: @TheUnholy, that's correct. The intent of this answer was to show how to use `find` to process files and not directories. The 'payload' of the `find` command (which is a simple `sed` command in this case) can be modified to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

To springboard on [paxdiablo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) answer, I cobbled this alias together, and added it to my bash aliases as 'recursive sed': `rsed` :

```
rsed() {
  [[ -z $2 ]] && echo "usage: ${FUNCNAME[0]} oldtext newtext" && return
  command find . -type f -exec sed -i "s/${1}/${2}/g" {} \;
}
```

Result:

```
> cat test/file
Hello how are you?
> rsed "Hello how are you?" "Fine thanks"
> cat test/file
Fine thanks
```